# Deleting existing content that was piped to a socket in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, ansi-escape

I am using Node with [ansi.js](https://github.com/TooTallNate/ansi.js) to write "Hello World!" to the terminal and erase it a second later.

```
var net = require('net');
var ansi = require('ansi');

var cursor = ansi(process.stdout);
setInterval(function() {
  cursor.write("Hello World!");

  setTimeout(function() {
    cursor.horizontalAbsolute(0).eraseLine();
  }, 1000);
}, 2000);
```

This code works as intended. "Hello World!" is written to the console and erased every two seconds.

I would like to replicate this behavior over a virtual terminal connection. I attempted this with the following code:

```
net.createServer(function(socket) {
  var cursor = ansi(socket);
  setInterval(function() {
    cursor.write("Hello World!");

    setTimeout(function() {
      cursor.horizontalAbsolute(0).eraseLine();
    }, 1000);
  }, 2000);
}).listen(1337);
```

When I run the above script and run `telnet 127.0.0.1 1337` in another terminal window, the second window receives "Hello World!" every two seconds but it is never erased. How do I erase data that has been piped to a socket with Node?

**Update:** ansi.js was not sending escape codes because socket.isTTY was false-y. Setting the option { enabled: true } overrides this behavior and fixes this issue.

I'm leaving this question open because it is useful to know that ansi.js will not send escape characters to sockets by default.